# Rights on web server in ASP.Net using forms authentification

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, security

I'm running an asp.net application using Forms Authentification via WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.

Once authenticated, the current thread principal is my form authentificated user. When accessing files on the web server, the principal doesn't have a specific account and it's not part of any group, so it's defaulting to the "Everyone" user.

A third party reporting engine that I'm using needs the execute rights on the root virtual directory. I do not want to give Execute rights to the "Everyone" group.

I'm looking for a configuration that will allow the authenticated user to access files under the application pool context. How can I configure that?

My host only gives me access to configure File Security for two user "ASP.Net" (Application pool) and Everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by our 3rd party reporting engine. The engine was dynamically compiling a dll at runtime then invoking a CodeDomProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource([...]). To my knowledge that was causing the problem.

The 3rd party offer the option to compile to a dll and include that as a reference. We used that solution.